# Build qtwebenginewidgets for mickledore

Tags: qt, yocto

I am trying to build some QT program with Yocto mickledore version.
I get an error like below.
`Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets`

When I include `qtwebengine` in `DEPENDS +=`, then I get another error.

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'qtwebengine' (but /home/pranav/Yocto/meta-pgtechlabs/recipes-examples/examples/examples.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
qtwebengine was skipped: Requires meta-python2 to be present.
```

I tried to checkout meta-python2 from :
https://git.openembedded.org/meta-python2

However, this doesn't support `mickledore` version.
What can I do to resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

In `meta-python2` use branch `kirkstone`, and add line below in your local.conf:

```
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-python2 = "mickledore kirkstone"
```

If errors still occur, add the output of the command below:

```
bitbake -e qtbase | grep ^PACKAGECONFIG
bitbake -e qtwebengine | grep ^PACKAGECONFIG
```

To check Widgets support in Qt5.